# How to make ruby stuff with no mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you make Ruby stuff with no mods. I can only have red dyed leather armor. And you can't dye wooden swords. so how do i get ruby with out mods?

Comment: A fun read about [ruby ore on the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_unused_features#Ruby) and why it is not used.

Comment: That's cool i wish Ruby's were not replaced with Emerald's.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is a ore that is only part of a mod. There is no way to get it outside of mods.

A popular mod that has ruby is [Orespawn](http://www.orespawn.com/)

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: The Ore spawn mod is great.

Comment: It is very popular. Have fun!